# Accessing MS-Exchange Calendar via C# for CRUD operations

Tags: c#, exchange-server

I would like to get some advice on how I can programatically access the Calendar in my exchange account please. THks.

Answer (score 3):

It depends whether you are coding a server or a client application, whether you can leverage Outlook on the client and which Exchange server you are talking to.

Client with Outlook: You can use the Outlook object model.

Exchange 2007/2010: Use the Exchange Managed API ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633710(EXCHG.80).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd633710%28EXCHG.80%29.aspx)).

Exchange 2000/2003: Use WebDAV. I have some articles on how to do this on my website.

Have a look at my website (http://www.infinitec.de), I have several articles on accessing Exchange programmatically.

Comment: Any idea how to determine what version Exchange it is?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the relevant classes and interfaces defined in [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb610835.aspx) - take a look at [AppointmentItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.appointmentitem.aspx), for example.  There are various "How To" scenarios described there that should get you started.

A broader set of Calendar Automation examples can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff184628.aspx).